# Proving basic set theoretic identities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to better understand how very basic properties of sets are proven in set theory. Few examples are provided below. Note that $a \in \mathbb R$, $b \in \mathbb R, v \in \mathbb R$ in all the examples.

$1.$
$$a=b \Leftrightarrow a \in \{v |v=b\}$$

$2.$

$$S=\bigcup_{s\in S}\{s\}$$

$3.$

$$\{a|a\in V \subset \mathbb N\} = \bigcup_{x \in V}\{a|a=x \}$$

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Comment: For 1, what does it mean $a \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ ? that $\varphi(a)$ holds.

Comment: Thus, $a \in \{ v \mid v=b \}$ implies $a=b$.

Comment: The vice versa is trivial...

Comment: For 2, use the def of [(set) Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions).

Comment: So, [you were not kidding](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2363762/), after all? Wow. Just to let me understand better what is going on (which floors me, to be honest), do you consider that the identity $$\{a\mid a=v\}=\{v\}$$ requires a proof?

Comment: It objectively requires a proof in every introductory set theory book -- for example, Introduction to Set Theory by Monk (1969). Without a proof that assertion is just symbol-pushing, although that wouldn't bother most mathematicians since that statement is a direct consequence of the class-comprehension axiom and the undefined notions in set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define $A=\{v~|~v=b\}$ and prove $a=b\Leftrightarrow a\in A$. But this holds directly by definition of the set $A$. You can conclude $\{v~|~v=b\}=\{b\}$.
2. Define $B=\bigcup_{s\in S}\{s\}$ and prove $S=B$.

   $S\subset B$:

   Let be $\sigma\in S$, then we conclude $\sigma\in\{\sigma\}\subset \bigcup_{s\in S}\{s\}=B$.

   $S\supset B$:

   Let be $\sigma\in B$. By definition of $B$ exists $s\in S$ such that $\sigma\in\{s\}$. This implies $\sigma=s\in S$.
3. Define $C=\{a~|~a\in V\}$ and $D=\bigcup_{x\in V}\{a~|~a=x\}$. Consider $C=V$ and $\{a~|~a=x\}=\{x\}$ with $1.$. Therefore $C=D$ is the same as in $2.$.

Answer (score 1):

These facts are all direct consequences of the logical context we are working in when we make set-theoretical assertions -- in other words, they are a direct result of the axioms (assumptions) made in set theory.

1. $A=\{v|v=b\}$ is read as "the class of all sets $v$ such that $v=b$".

Suppose that there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\neq b$ -- then we have a contradiction, since $$a\in A=\{v|v=b\}\implies a=b,$$ but we have assumed that $a\in A$ and $a\neq b$. Since we assume that our set theory is consistent we cannot have $a=b$ and $a\neq b$, so we avoid this contradiction by concluding that there is no $a\in A$ such that $a\neq b$. Consequently there is only one object in $A$ -- namely $b$, thus $A=\{b\}$. Now suppose $a=b$; then since $A=\{b\}$, we have that $a\in A$. This completes the proof of 1.

The other two facts are established in much the same fashion, and we could have argued constructively both ways or by contradiction both ways -- if this still seems like hand-waving or like I am merely asserting what is obvious and not 'making mathematical assertions', I suggest you look into the role of formal logic in mathematics.

Comment: Do you have any sources that would help with elementary proofs in first order logic?

Comment: The only primer on logic I've read was the beginning of Introduction to Set Theory by J. Donald Monk, however I believe that you should be considering what $\{v|v=b\}$ actually means and a first-order logic book probably wouldn't cover this.  Understanding the role of logic in set theory is subtly different than understanding first-order logic itself, as we apply logical predicates to collections of objects and manipulate them while logic just deals with the predicates.

Comment: For example, $v=b$ is a predicate while $\{v|v=b\}$ is the class containing all sets $v$ that satisfy the predicate $v=b$. By the extensionality axiom we have that $b=b$ and no class besides $b$ is equal to $b$, or else it would also be $b$. This is what I mean -- we have applied the predicate $v=b$ to a collection of sets, and we conclude that there must be only one set in this collection due to the nature of this particular predicate.